# How to access this element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've got this element that's not precisely defined as a div or anything but just white space popping up inside the html. Can't get to it with jQuery to remove it.
Type of element is highlighted in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: your image is not clear

Comment: try this - jQuery('.product-container').text()

Comment: why remove it with javascript? You can't remove by server side? Some process have add this space.

Comment: The image is fine if you open it up, but it doesn't provide any insight into the source of the element. Maybe you can stop it from ever being created instead of deleting it once it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Comment: See here: [How to manipulate text nodes in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329042/how-to-manipulate-text-nodes-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not simply.

jQuery can map objects with structure. It's very hard to catch just whitespaces as DOM elements and remove them.

I cant suggest 2 alternatives:

1. Use jQuery to get parent tag, extract innerHTML and user regex to remove "extra whitespaces" between tags:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var container = $('.product-container');
     container.html(container.html().replace(/>\s+</i, '><'))
   });
   ```
2. Use css to clean how looks my content inside that tag as suggests thirtydog [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Im not expert, but maybe you could use .prev() method.

Something like

```
$('#main .content').prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript to select it:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByClassName("filter-navigation")[0].nextSibling;
```

and remove it:

```
textNode.parentElement.removeChild(textNode);
```

jQuery simplifies the selection a bit, but the removal has to be done the same way since jQuery doesn't like removing text nodes:

```
var textNode = $("#main").find("filter-navigation")[0].nextSibling;
textNode.parentElement.removeChild(textNode);
```